# Create ArrayList from comma separated String without whitespace

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Say I have a String with randomly placed spaces and commas around other characters.

```
String str = "item1 , it em 2,  ite m 3"
```

How do I get an ArrayList with the items like

```
[item1, item2, item3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
String str = "item1 , it em 2,  ite m 3"
String[] splitArray = str.split(",");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s:splitArray)
{
    list.add(s.replace(" ", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun :-)

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String inputString = "item1 , it em 2,  ite m 3";
List<String> stringList = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(inputString).split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```
    //Given string
    String str = "item1 , it em 2,  ite m 3";

    //Match one or more occurrence of space in the string and replace by empty
    String pattern = "\\s+";
    str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "");

    //Split by , and convert to ArrayList
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));

    for(String temp: items)
        System.out.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 's parallelSetAll

```
String str = "item1 , it em 2,  ite m 3";
String[] stringlist = str.split(",");
Arrays.parallelSetAll(stringlist, (i) -> stringlist[i].replaceAll(" ",""));
```